# Как обновить окно с графиком matplotlib

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, matplotlib, рисование

Есть небольшая программа, которая считывает показания с датчиков и отображает коды датчиков в `QListWidgets`. Затем при нажатии на пункт в этом списке строит его график в этом же окне (пример на картинке)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

После нажатия на другой пункт `QListWidgets`, график должен быть перерисован, 
но он не перерисовывается до тех пор, пока не обновлю размер окна, а методы `update`, `repaint` не приносят никакого результата.

В чем может быть ошибка?

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        
        self.detectorList = DetectorList()
        
        self.filesNames = None
        self.resize(1200,600)
        
        mainBox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        dataBox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.btnOpenFile = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Выбор файла')
        self.btnOpenFile.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_open_file)

        self.kksView = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.kksView.installEventFilter(self)
        self.kksView.clicked.connect(self.on_draw_line)

        dataBox.addWidget(self.btnOpenFile)
        dataBox.addWidget(self.kksView)
        
        #MPL для рисования графика
        self.canvas = Canvas(self)
        mainBox.addLayout(dataBox, stretch=1)
        mainBox.addWidget(self.canvas,stretch=2)
               
        self.setLayout(mainBox)
        self.show()
        
    def on_clicked_open_file(self):
        '''Выбор файлов'''
        self.filesNames = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, 'Open files')[0]
        if self.filesNames:
            print('readFiles', self.filesNames)
            self.kksView.clear()
            self.detectorList.read_files(self.filesNames)
            self.kksView.addItems(self.detectorList.get_all_kks())
            print('readFiles finished', self.filesNames)
    
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()        
    def on_draw_line(self):
        index = self.kksView.currentIndex()
        kks = self.kksView.model().data(index)
        detector = self.detectorList.get_detector(kks)
        dateList = np.array(detector.get_date())
        indicationList = np.array(detector.get_indication())
        self.canvas.clear_plot()
        self.canvas.add_plot(dateList,indicationList)
        #это работает
        #self.resize(self.window().width()-1,self.window().height()-1)
        self.canvas.update()
        self.update()
        self.window().update()
        self.window().repaint()
    
    def eventFilter(self, source:QtWidgets.QListWidget, event:QtGui.QHideEvent):
        '''обработка событий при клике на listview'''
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ContextMenu and source is self.kksView):
            menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
            menu.addAction('Draw graph', self.on_draw_graph)
            menu.addAction('Close window', QtWidgets.qApp.quit)
            if menu.exec_(event.globalPos()):
                item:QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem = source.itemAt(event.pos())
        return super(MyWindow,self).eventFilter(source,event)
    
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_draw_graph(self):
        index = self.kksView.currentIndex()
        kks = self.kksView.model().data(index)
        print(kks)
        kksList = [kks]
        detectors = self.detectorList.get_detectors(kksList)
        draw_plot(detectors)
class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    
    def __init__(self, parent = None, width = 5, height = 5, dpi = 100):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width,height), dpi = dpi)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.add_plot()
        
    def add_plot(self,x=[],y=[]):
        self.ax.plot(x,y)
    def clear_plot(self):
        self.ax.clear()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы предоставили не воспроизводимый пример. 
На маленьком своем примере, 
попробую продемонстрировать как это обычно делается:

- создаем объект `self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)`
- вставляем в макет `layout.addWidget(self.canvas, 0, 1, 6, 1)`
- когда нам нужно что-то нарисовать/перерисовать , вызываем метод `_update_canvas`. 
  У меня обновляется по событию таймера, 
  вам нужно вызвать этот метод по нажатию на элемент `QListWidget`.

---

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._main)

        self.btnOpenFile = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Выбор файла')
        self.kksView = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.kksView.addItems(['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', ])

        self.fig = Figure() 
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)

        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self._main)
        layout.addWidget(self.btnOpenFile, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas, 0, 1, 6, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.kksView, 1, 0, 5, 1)                

        self._ax = self.fig.subplots()

        self._timer = self.canvas.new_timer(
            100, [(self._update_canvas, (), {})])
        self._timer.start()

    def _update_canvas(self):
        self._ax.clear()
        t = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
        self._ax.plot(t, np.sin(t + time.time()))
        self.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = ApplicationWindow()
    app.show()
    qapp.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: S.Nick, огромное спасибо. Добавил self.canvas.draw() после прорисовки линии, и все стало обновляться.

Comment: @AlexandrSamodurov пожалуйста