# Как обновить/перерисовать график matplotlib в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, matplotlib

Есть график, который при нажатии кнопки "Применить" отрисовывается в виджете `MplWidget`.

Необходимо, чтобы при изменении параметров:

> **n_1**, **n_2** или же **phi**

и следующем нажатии кнопки `Применить` график обновился. 
Как это можно реализовать?

**Minimap_example.py:**

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from Otrajenie_Lucha import refraction_reflection_graph
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class MyMplCanavas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self, fig, parent = None):
        self.fig = fig
        FigureCanvasQTAgg.__init__(self, self.fig)

class EMW_REF_APP(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('main.ui', self)
        self.resize(1366, 768)
        self.init_UI()
        self.connectUi()

    def init_UI(self):
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('project_icon.png'))

    def connectUi(self):
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.prepare_canavas_and_toolbar)

    def prepare_canavas_and_toolbar(self):
        n_1 = float(self.ui.lineEdit.text())
        n_2 = float(self.ui.lineEdit_2.text())
        phi = float(self.ui.lineEdit_6.text())
        self.fig = refraction_reflection_graph(n_1, n_2, phi)
        self.companovka_for_mpl = QVBoxLayout(self.MplWidget)
        self.canvas = MyMplCanavas(self.fig)
        self.companovka_for_mpl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2QT(self.canvas, self)
        self.companovka_for_mpl.addWidget(self.toolbar)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = EMW_REF_APP()
mainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Otrajenie_Lucha.py:**

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

def refraction_reflection_graph(n_1, n_2, phi):
    arrow_length = 50
    phi_rad = math.radians(phi)
    try:
        theta = math.asin(math.sin(phi_rad)*n_1/n_2)
    except ValueError:
        theta = math.pi/2
    x_pad = -math.sin(phi_rad) * arrow_length
    y_pad = math.cos(phi_rad) * arrow_length
    x_otr = math.sin(phi_rad) * arrow_length
    x_prelom = math.sin(theta)*arrow_length
    y_prelom = -math.cos(theta)*arrow_length
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(5.11, 3.31), dpi=100)
    plt.xlim(-60,60)
    plt.ylim(-60,60)
    ax.arrow(x_pad, y_pad, -x_pad, -y_pad, label='', width=0.5, color='blue', head_length=3)
    if ((n_1 != n_2) and (phi_rad != 0)):
        if (theta == math.pi/2):
            ax.arrow(0, 0, x_otr, y_pad, label='', width=0.5, color='r')
        else:
            ax.arrow(0, 0, x_prelom, y_prelom, label='', width=0.5, color='g')
            ax.arrow(0, 0, x_otr, y_pad, label='', width=0.5, color='r')
    elif ((phi_rad == 0) or (n_1 == n_2)):
        ax.arrow(0, 0, x_prelom, y_prelom, label='', width=0.5, color='g')
    ax.set_title('', fontsize=14)
    if (n_1 > n_2):
        rect = patches.Rectangle((-60, 0), 120, 60, linewidth=1, edgecolor='blue', facecolor='blue')
        rect.set_alpha(0.1)
        ax.add_patch(rect)
    elif (n_1 < n_2):
        rect = patches.Rectangle((-60, 0), 120, -60, linewidth=1, edgecolor='blue', facecolor='blue')
        rect.set_alpha(0.1)
        ax.add_patch(rect)
    else:
        rect = patches.Rectangle((-60, -60), 120, 120, linewidth=1, edgecolor='blue', facecolor='blue')
        rect.set_alpha(0.1)
        ax.add_patch(rect)
    ax.grid(which='major', linewidth=1)
    ax.grid(which='minor', linestyle='--', color='gray', linewidth=0.5)
    ax.tick_params(which='major', length=10, width=2)
    ax.tick_params(which='minor', length=5, width=1)
    ax.legend()
    return fig
```

**main.ui:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="enabled">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1366</width>
    <height>768</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>730</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>1.0</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>730</x>
      <y>90</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>1.5</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_6">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>730</x>
      <y>270</y>
      <width>41</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>45</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>660</x>
      <y>330</y>
      <width>121</width>
      <height>51</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Применить</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="MplWidget" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>830</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>521</width>
      <height>341</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1366</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: я думаю, что вам будет полезно посмотреть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1214761/typeerror-sip-wrappertype-object-is-not-subscriptable/1215415#1215415 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115260/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2-pyqt/1115319#1115319

Comment: + https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1117324/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b2-gui-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0/1117791#1117791

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я отметил для вас строки, в которые внес изменения, попробуйте.

Обратите внимание, что у вас происходит утечка памяти. По ходу теста получил сообщение:

> RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. 
> Figures created through the pyplot
> nterface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this
> warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`)

Проверьте модуль **Otrajenie_Lucha.py** все ли у вас там хорошо!

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
#from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT                  # backend_qt5agg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from Otrajenie_Lucha import refraction_reflection_graph


class MyMplCanavas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self, fig, parent = None):
#        self.fig = fig
#        FigureCanvasQTAgg.__init__(self, self.fig)
        super(MyMplCanavas, self).__init__(fig)
        

class EMW_REF_APP(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('q1247551.ui', self)
        self.resize(1366, 768)
        self.init_UI()
        self.connectUi()

    def init_UI(self):
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Ok.png'))
        self.canvas = None                                                        # +++
        self.companovka_for_mpl = QVBoxLayout(self.MplWidget)                     # +++

    def connectUi(self):
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.prepare_canavas_and_toolbar)

    def prepare_canavas_and_toolbar(self):
        n_1 = float(self.ui.lineEdit.text())
        n_2 = float(self.ui.lineEdit_2.text())
        phi = float(self.ui.lineEdit_6.text())
#        self.fig = refraction_reflection_graph(n_1, n_2, phi)
        fig = refraction_reflection_graph(n_1, n_2, phi)
        
#        self.companovka_for_mpl = QVBoxLayout(self.MplWidget)                     # ---

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        if self.canvas:       
            self.companovka_for_mpl.removeWidget(self.toolbar)
            self.companovka_for_mpl.removeWidget(self.canvas)
            self.toolbar.deleteLater()                                                       
            self.canvas.deleteLater()
            self.canvas.hide()
            self.toolbar.hide()            
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       
            
        self.canvas = MyMplCanavas(fig)                #(self.fig)
        self.companovka_for_mpl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2QT(self.canvas, self)
        self.companovka_for_mpl.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = EMW_REF_APP()
mainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да! Действительно то, что нужно, большое спасибо! Если вам не затруднит, подскажите, пожалуйста, последнее: как я могу добавлять дополнительные графики в tabWidget с той же функцией обновления? Я попробовал добавить в нижний виджет график, он отрисовался, но опять же, при нажатии на "Применить" первый график дублируется, а новый - обновляется

Comment: @Keineprogrammer если у вас возникают другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос. Приведите минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: Я разобрался благодаря вашему примеру, спасибо большое

Comment: @Keineprogrammer если мои примеры помогают вам и учат чему-то новому, не забывайте отмечать их как полезные.

Comment: Я отметил, но из-за моего малого рейтинга ваш ответ не был показан как "полезный", но был засчитан; отметил ещё раз. Всего вам хорошего!

Comment: @Keineprogrammer и вам всего доброго